# How do I create a page to display the html source code (only) of a website I created from Google Sheets?

Tags: python, html, api, flask, google-sheets

I have a calendar I created from Google Sheets using an API. I want to create another page(route) to display the html code (not the rendered template) of the calendar.  Here is my code:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google.oauth2 import service_account

from flask import Flask
from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request, url_for, 
session

import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
     SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = 'removed for security'

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# Call the Sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                            range="new!A2:D9").execute()

header = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                            range="new!A1:D1").execute()
                                                                    

request = sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, 
         range="new!A10", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body= 
         {"values":newvalues}).execute()


@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
        values = result.get('values', [])
        headers = header.get('values', [])

          return render_template("index.html", values=values, headers=headers)


 @app.route('/text', methods=["GET", "POST"])
 def text():
           t = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000')
           return (t.content)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run()
```

The '/text' route displays the page exactly like the '/' page.  I want it do only return the html code not the rendered template.

Comment: you can use autoescaping https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#autoescaping

Comment: I've looked at the documentation you referenced but I'm not quite sure how to use this.  Would this be a separate function or a line within the def text() function?  Is this meant to remove the .html extension and read the filename index.html as just index?  I'm confused.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: what you want to show , the code same as which you write in  html file with jinja syntaxor the one that is rendered without jinja syntax by jinja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the mime type of the response to `text/plain` using [`make_response`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.make_response):

```
from flask import app, make_response, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    resp = make_response(render_template('template.html'))
    resp.mimetype = 'text/plain'
    return resp
```

Comment: It is close to what I'm looking for... however it doesn't show the full html because it doens't loop through the spreadsheet data.  For example in the header tags it only displays <thead></thead> but the page should show <thead>
             <tr><th>Date</th>
             <th>Region</th>
             <th>Tournament</th>
             <th>City</th>
         </tr></thead>

Comment: Could you show me how you have adapted the code? On the other hand, if you want to get all the values, I don't understand why you call `'http://127.0.0.1:5000'` instead of using the same `index` structure adapting the last lines.

Comment: I modified the following function and also added the import request for make_response.  Sorry,  I can't figure out how to get the code in the proper format.   
     `@app.route('/text', methods=["GET", "POST"])
       def text():
              resp = make_response(render_template('index.html'))
              resp.mimetype = 'text/plain'
              return resp`

Comment: Why don't you use `render_template("index.html", values=values, headers=headers)`?